# how to set host in botfront helm and update parameters in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, rasa-nlu

I have installed and deployed botfront on kubernetes, but when I go to interface using node ip and port where service is running it prompts me to add root_url like this

[image]

I got to know that it can be put in config.yaml which is used to update helm but it is not taking ip and takes only domain name, I need some guidance over this since I tried google DNS API and that also didn't help and apart from it how can I update rasa parameters, like editing rasa host, adding NLU pipelines etc because rasa is not reachable from UI so in order to fix that I need to modify helm first.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the **ingress controller** to manage the traffic and expose the UI.

So your service will be running as the Cluster IP or Node port and ingress which will manage the traffic and expose the UI.

inside config.yaml file

```
botfront:
   app:
# The complete external host of the Botfront application (eg. botfront.yoursite.com). It must be set even if running on a        private or local DNS (it populates the ROOT_URL).
       host: botfront.yoursite.com
```

and you can install the Nginx ingress controller and create the ingress object so traffic some inside and you can access the service.

it helm is already creating the ingress you have to install the ingress controller : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/

You can check helm is creating ingress or not using the : `kubectl get ingress`

**Update** :

you can also use the service type **LoadBalancer** and map **IP** to **DNS** and use the **domain** **name** inside the config of botfront.

Comment: if I use nodeip and port I still see the interface coming up, but due to host not configured in yaml file it pops up with that image, any help on configuring the host? or do you think ingress alone can take care and it wont run into such blocker again?

Comment: inside configuration, you can not give the NodeIp as it can get change anytime. with ingress you won't be facing any issue if you are configuring domain using the ingress.

Comment: but yaml doesn't take ip that's where I'm stuck, if you see the above file content you have shared host needs to be alphanumeric, there's some regex matching goes on when we upgrade helm and that time it fails, so I want to know how can I set a name for an ip, or as per you if I simply take ip of ingress and put it that will take care?

Comment: you have to use the ingress, add ingress IP to DNS so you will get the domain name. you can use that domain in config. if you don't have domain you can use the free domain like for testing.https://www.freenom.com/en/index.html?lang=en

Comment: cant I use nodeip and port just for the sake of temporary testing? since my node ip is unchanged for like 5 days now.

Comment: yes you can use it, for sure. no issue into but bot front not supporting the IP in the config you have to pass the domain name in string.